# Why are images not showing in my Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I have made a menu in my Apple Watch app. I can see images when force touching but when I use my custom images I just see a black circle and nothing else.

> Here is my Apple Watch screen. Add three images are displaying but the
>   custom image is not displaying for drink.

I am create this menu in my `storyboard` interface.

[image]

Comment: You have to add the images to your WatchKit Extension target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your custom icon image follows the guidelines set out in the HIG: https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/specifications/

You need an 80x80 icon for the 42mm Watch and 70x70 for the 28mm Watch. Your icon's background should be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

For mine, it is ok.

First, remove the transparencies and alpha channels (this can be done simply from Save As dialog in Preview)

Second, You must use the correct sizes:

- 80*80
- 70*70

NOTE: The first one is for 42mm one and the second is for 38mm one.